# Why is my Selenium click() causing a timeout?

Tags: selenium, timeout, click, webdriver

One of my Selenium tests issues a click on a button to create a new user:

```
seleniumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save']")).click();
```

However, the validation fails (it is meant to fail!) so that a `<div>` is displayed to inform the user to correct some input fields. This works very well manually, but the automated test aborts with the following error message:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out waiting for action to finish
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Timer.run(Timer.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.doCommand(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:75)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.click(DefaultSelenium.java:193)
    at com.holcim.logon.admin.web.admin.UserTest.createUser(UserTest.java:354
```

How is it possible that a click() ends up in a timeout? And how could I possible fix this?

Comment: What webdriver are you using? If it's Chrome, when it clicks the button, have a look in the Chrome Developer tools to see if anything is still being fetched.

Comment: I am using Firefox, not Chrome.

Comment: I found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268255/selenium-webdriver-throws-timeout-exceptions-sporadically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible solution to your problem:
1) instead of xPath find css selector of the needed element.
it gonna be something like:

```
String cssSelector = "input[value='Save']";
```

but before you gonna use it verify in firepath, firebug addon in ffox that needed element is located properly.

[image: firepath verify]

After we obtained needed css selector, we can use approach that always works. using js function that
will perform a click on the needed element.

```
public void jsClick(String cssSelector){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

Hope this works for you now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and It was due to not enough delay for loading page

You can increase timeout delay for loading page using following command

driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,timespan));