# Why is Selenium + Firefox freezing while loading pages?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running the latest version of Firefox and Selenium in C#. I'm automating a crawler to find data in a web app. The server is super slow, so I've had to add in many waits plus put in initial wait using thread sleep.

So my crawler gets a list of items, then iterates: it has to load the details of each item by clicking on its id. Then it goes back (these navigation controls are all built into the web app, no browser controls used), rinse and repeat. The server shows a progress spinner during loading details and going back. The crawler reaches the same item each time and locks, eg: the progress spinner freezes and Firefox crashes.

I've tried a couple of different things including using background threads, deleting all cookies, and checking if my memory is overloading. I haven't noticed any peaks in memory (in task manager). I also tried restarting web driver but it doesn't really work out well because this is a web app.

Is there something I'm overlooking? (I tried to be as clear and elaborate as possible)

Forgot to mention, when I stop the program the page 'unfreezes' and I can continue use from that point.

Comment: If it's not too AJAX & JavaScript heavy, you could look into PhantomJS to speed it up.

Comment: Speed isn't the problem, if I had not added sleeps to add an initial delay for explicit waits then the server just gives me an error page when the page isn't done loading and an element can't be found. Also, it's written in js and AJAX.

Comment: Turns out that for some reason Firefox seems to do this but IE is fine. I will work with IE instead but I'm still curious as to why Firefox is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a known problem with C# selenium web bindings 2.39 and earlier. This should now be fixed in 2.40. The problem was to do with a deadlock in the web bindings code when redirecting console logging from firefox. If you upgrade to 2.40 it should solve it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181669/746754) under the heading 'Update 25th Feb 2014' for more information.

Comment: I haven't tested this, as I've already switched from using Selenium to just using a WebBrowser control, but it seems like a reasonable explanation, thank you.