# Selenium timeout on ExecuteScript

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I'm getting timeouts when executing scripts with Selenium no matter what I try and do to avoid them.

I first set the timeouts to something ridiculously long:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));               
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Later, I run a script which is expected to take a long time (it's doing a long running POST request). No mater whether I use `ExecuteScript` or `ExecuteAsyncScript`, the request times out at 60 seconds.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this? Even a hack or workaround would be good at this point.

Comment: if this is firefox, you can try to alter profile: `profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time", 0);` 0 means wait forever

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Does it have something similar?

Comment: I found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268255/selenium-webdriver-throws-timeout-exceptions-sporadically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your favorite `RemoteWebDriver` (`FireFoxDriver` or `ChromeDriver`) takes a `commandTimeout` parameter in some of its constructor overloads.

```
_driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), new ChromeOptions(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
```

There appears to be no way to change this after the instance is constructed, so you need to make sure to set it this way. This will prevent the timeouts.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get a 60s time out exception from `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteAsyncScript`

Comment: hi @Jack I"m getting this error when i also use the ExecuteAsyncScript method even though the script has executed.  U use to use the other method of ExecuteScript but that doesn't seem to work anymore.  Did you find a way around this. Thanks

Comment: @skinnyWill: I switch to using Firefox driver for some reason (not for timeout specifically) but on Firefox, I did initiliaze it like this: https://pastebin.com/nPVuH4k0 Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

The connection to the driver has a 60 second timeout. On way to change it is to edit the protected field `RemoteWebDriver.DefaultCommandTimeout`:

```
typeof(RemoteWebDriver)
    .GetField("DefaultCommandTimeout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Another way would be to set a variable once the request returns and then wait for it:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(@"
    window._result = null;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            window._result = this.responseText);
        }
    };
    req.open('GET', '...');
    req.send();
");

var response = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .Until(_ => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_).ExecuteScript("return window._result;"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked for me. Despite changing the timeout, it still throws an exception at 60 seconds. In addition, I'm POSTing a form, which for whatever reason doesn't seem to work from `XMLHttpRequest`. I'm using this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/1195036.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. You need to change the DefaultCommandTimeout before creating a WebDriver. In fact, CommandTimeout is one of the constructor parameters for the WebDriver. Just setting it there is a better solution, but I'll upvote this for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would try waiting for the whole document to be in the ready state:

```
  var driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    driverWait.Until(
            driverA =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var browserStatus = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driverA).
ExecuteScript("return document.readyState");
                    return string.Compare("complete", browserStatus,
 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
                }
                catch (NoSuchWindowException)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```